# IE9: How to make Unicode characters appear properly?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, unicode, internet-explorer-9

I am designing a website (www.lathamcity.com) where I use the Unicode character &#x2022 to represent a bullet point in my header.  When I load the page in IE9, however, the bullet point does not appear and in its place is the Unicode for the character.

My charset is defined in the HTML document with

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and the code for the header is

```
    <td id="infoCell" class="header">   
        <a href="/resume.pdf" class="header" target="_blank">R&#233sum&#233</a> 
        &nbsp &#x2022 &nbsp 
        <a href="mailto:acl68@case.edu" class="header" target="_blank">E-mail</a> 
        &nbsp &#x2022 &nbsp
        <a href="https://github.com/orthogonal/" class="header" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
        &nbsp &#x2022 &nbsp
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/1146679/andrew-latham" class="header" target="_blank">StackOverflow</a>
        &nbsp &#x2022 &nbsp
        <a href="http://main.uschess.org/assets/msa_joomla/MbrDtlMain.php?12842311" class="header" target="_blank">USCF</a>
    </td>
```

The characters appear correctly in Chrome and Firefox.  What am I doing wrong, why is it happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon.

```
&#x2022
```

should be

```
&#x2022;
```

Similarly, `&nbsp` and `&#233` should end with a `;`.

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references) says:

> **Hexadecimal numeric character reference**
>
> The ampersand must be followed by a U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#), which must be followed by either a U+0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X character (x) or a U+0058 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X character (X), which must then be followed by one or more digits in the range U+0030 DIGIT ZERO (0) to U+0039 DIGIT NINE (9), U+0061 LATIN SMALL LETTER A to U+0066 LATIN SMALL LETTER F, and U+0041 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to U+0046 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F, representing a base-sixteen integer that corresponds to a Unicode code point that is allowed according to the definition below. **The digits must then be followed by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).**

Comment: This is bug in IE 9 (in Quirks Mode), since by the spefications, `&#x2022` is valid here. But it has always been good and recommended practice to end all entity references (like `&nbsp;`) and character references (like `&#233;`) with a semicolon, partly because omitting it has triggered various browser bugs.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, which specification?  My reading of the [ambiguous ampersand](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand) section is that it is an error though a recoverable one outside RCDATA, attribute values, and foreign elements.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That may be true in SGML, but HTML5 is not SGML, I'm sorry to say. By the way, following with a space would be OK, but I'm pretty sure that following by a letter (as in the first line) would be a no-no even with SGML!

Comment: The current HTML specifications are HTML 4.01 and some XHTML specs, whereas HTML5 is a mutable draft. In HTML 4.01, the constructs discussed are valid, as you can check at http://validator.w3.org . The reason for mentioning that this is an IE 9 bug is that there is probably a lot of existing code that relies on the omissibility of semicolons (and may thus break on IE 9 Quirks Mode) since browsers have generally allowed it.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, don't wait for HTML5 to become a non-draft.  http://blog.whatwg.org/html-is-the-new-html5 : "The WHATWG HTML spec can now be considered a "living standard". It's more mature than any version of the HTML specification to date, so it made no sense for us to keep referring to it as merely a draft. We will no longer be following the "snapshot" model of spec development..."  HTML4 is obsolete.  HTML5 is now what browsers target and is called just HTML since Hickson and co. have dropped version numbers for the draft as a whole.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, Also, validator.w3.org is obsolete.  You can use http://validator.nu/ which shows `Error: Character reference was not terminated by a semicolon.` for `<body><p>&#x2022</p>↩</body>`.