# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' (...)

Tags: javascript, ajax, netbeans

Seems like a common error, but none of the solutions I've found searching have proved successfull (replacing & with `&amp;` is one). I have a simple Javascript (AJAX) that includes a couple of double if statements. The script works fine in both Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9 which reports an error on the same line as Netbeans (the entity name must immediately follow the '&' (...)).

Hoping that someone here can spot the error or provide clues to where I shoud look.

```
function getNames(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // The line below is what produces the error.
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
            var ul = document.getElementById("names");
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            if (ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                while (ul.childNodes.length >= 1) {
                    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] != ":@") {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerHTML = newListItem = arr[i];
                    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "./ext/get_names.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I think you need to replace `if (xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4)` with `if (xmlhttp.status == 200 &amp;&amp; xmlhttp.readyState == 4)`

Comment: Ye, I've tried that. That broke the script completely in all browsers.

Comment: Try nesting it then: `if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a particular reason, the cleanest solution is usually moving your javascript code to an external file.

Besides avoiding most odd problems with browsers interpreting included javascript differently, it also makes things more cacheable.

Comment: Alright, that made some headway. IE9 now reports that <pre>xmlhttp.status == 200</pre> is producing an "unspecified error" .. whatever that means. I've tried nesting them like Paul Tomblin suggested.

Comment: If you moved the scripts to external files, you should not need to escape or reformat anything, in fact you should just write the code without worrying about it being included in a html page. See http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/script_tags.html#hsExC for example.

Comment: True. I'm back to the original script now. However it still does not work in IE, but I guess I should create another question for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to write your own xmlhttp stuff, just use jquery - it has an "ajax" method that takes care of all that.

Answer (score 4):

You can enclose the script within a CDATA section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.write("&&");
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jukka K. Korpela explained an IE9 quirks mode behavior in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8947186/20394)

> This is bug in IE 9 (in Quirks Mode), since by the spefications, `&#x2022` is valid here. But it has always been good and recommended practice to end all entity references (like `&nbsp;`) and character references (like `&#233;`) with a semicolon, partly because omitting it has triggered various browser bugs.

I disagree on what the specification says, but IE9 quirks mode may be the culprit.